# what's the best http code to use for detecting that a website is down?

Tags: http, web, monitoring

We want to know whether our website is down or not from client, and basically what we do is to shot a httpclient call to GET the root domain page of our website. And we are getting different http status code returned like below. The question is which one of the following is definitely indicate that our website is down temporarily?

404
500
503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 404 is Not Found
- 500 is Internal Server Error
- 503 is Service Unavailable

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Unless you have a redirection on the URL you use to check website status you should expect a 200 OK response only.